# Loading Packages with Parameters

Tags: packages

I have some packages that uses database connections inside it, let's call it `ConnPackage`. The connection IP is a public package variable, and has a default value:

```
$connectionIP="127.0.0.1".
```

This variable is used to read database values when the package is loading. So change it value after package load don't solve the problem. The problem is similar to pass args in shell wolfram script, but must be done in the notebook.

**The question is:**

How could I read the `ConnPackage`, using `Needs[]`, but setting `$connectionIP` to be another value?

**UPDATE**

I can solve the problem defining a variable in `System`. But I don't feel it's a good pattern. Here is my attempt. Inside `ConnPackage` I can do:

```
$connectionIP=If[StringQ[#],#,"127.0.0.1"]&[System`$argConnectionIP]
```

So, if there is no value in `` System`$argConnectionIP ``, the standard IP will be load, otherwise it will use `` System`$argConnectionIP ``.

Comment: Would using `SetDelayed` help in your case?

Comment: @YvesKlett SetDelayed don't help in this case, as the package use `$connectionIP` as it runs to load other definitions. @OleksandrR. I made an update with how I solved it, but I don't fell it's a good way.

Comment: I saw you ping in Chat.  I'm afraid I don't really understand the question at the moment.  First, what is wrong with your own solution?  Second, why do you have to use ``System` ``?  Cannot you use ``ConnPackage`$connectionIP`` too?  Perhaps I don't actually understand what you wish to accomplish; if that's the case pardon me.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard yes! Much better using `ConnPackage`, I forgot `BeginPackage` reads `System` and the loaded package.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard about your first question, with Kuba solution I don't need to put any extra code inside `ConnPackage`.

Comment: Why is adding code to the package a problem?  Do you not have control of its content?  I get the feeling I'm still not seeing the entire picture here.  Anyway I'm glad the context thing is useful to you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can catch next assignment with `TagSetDelayed`:

```
$connectionIP /: Set[$connectionIP, _] := (ClearAll[$connectionIP]; 
                                           $connectionIP = "whatever");
Needs["ConnPackage`"]
```

You should make this `TagSetDelayed` statement in proper context so use `Begin` or provide explicit context.

Does it fit your needs?

---

Different approach.

If you know what is done inside the package, and you know that `$connectionIP` is a ***constant*** you can just do:

```
$connectionIP = "whatever";                (*keep in mind the context*)

SetAttributes[$connectionIP, Protected];

Needs["ConnPackage`"];
```

Comment: Very nice! I like both ways. Nice use of `UpValues`. Tks +1

Comment: @Murta Great! I'm glad I can help :)