# How can I pass replacement rules to a package-defined function and have it understand their context?

Tags: replacement, packages, contexts

I am writing a package where I would like to be able to pass replacement rules to a function inside the package and have the function manipulate its symbols using those replacement rules. However, I'm having some trouble implementing it.

(I'm rather baffled because the files used to work and no longer do, coinciding with a change from v10 to v10.1. However, I would be surprised if that is actually the cause as I feel the MWE below completely encapsulates the problem and it looks like a language issue, so instead it may be that I ran the files differently in ways that are hard to reconstruct.)

The specific thing I have in mind is this. Make two files, `testpackage.m` containing

```
BeginPackage["Test`"];
replace::usage = "Returns var/.rules.";
Begin["`Private`"];
replace[rules_] := ReplaceAll[var, rules]
End[];
EndPackage[];
```

and `testnotebook.nb` containing

```
Needs["Test`", "/path/to/testpackage.m"]

replace[var-> 0]
replace[Test`Private`var -> 0]
```

Open the notebook file on a fresh session and load the package. I would like the usage `replace[var-> 0]` to return `0` - that is, I would like `replace` to be able to tell `var` to zero itself. However, it returns `` Test`Private`var ``, which upon closer examination of the code is in fact a pretty reasonable thing for it to return. The reasonableness of this is compounded by the fact that `` replace[Test`Private`var -> 0] `` will return `0` as expected.

As I said, the usage `replace[var->0]` used to work fine for my bigger package, and indeed it can work fine in some circumstances (which I cannot pin down exactly, and which I have not been able to reproduce in this MWE yet) if the notebook file is opened on the same Mathematica instance (and thus kernel session) as the package file, with the package file (in practice, a `.m` auto-generated from a notebook) having been used to run the definition of `replace`.

So: I have some wonky code, which is probably returning the results it needs to but not the results I want it to, and I would like to amend it to return it to the desired behaviour. In particular: is there some way to take the call

```
ReplaceAll[var, rules]
```

and make it forget contexts for a minute?

Alternatively, I'm painfully aware of the possibility that this simply means that I've completely misunderstood the concept of contexts, and that what I want simply isn't doable. This would mean that the behaviour I want, for example, can only be produced by e.g. adding the symbol `var` to the `` Test` `` context, such as by adding the line

```
var::usage = "var is the variable that gets replaced";
```

below the usage message for `replace`. I'm reluctant to take such a step as the package is relatively big (and organically grown, so somewhat messy and without comprehensive unit tests, unfortunately) and I'm afraid of breaking something. If there are no shortcuts then I'm OK with it, but I would like to know if there's a hackier way to get the behaviour I want.

Comment: I feel that the better example is needed since this minimal one is just badly designed. User should only put `0` in `replace`. I don't recall any MMA function with similar usage. Even for solve etc. you have to tell MMA which are variables we are going to do something with in an expression.

Comment: related: [Loading Packages with Parameters](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71467/5478)

Comment: @Kuba I suspect that simply my original code is just badly designed, but it's probably not worth the effort to fix it given the future use it will get. Thanks all for your responses - they are all helpful. I'm accepting Chris's solution as it's the simplest to implement, though it is not very suitable for a package that one will distribute given the issues pointed out by Kuba and bbgodfrey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
replace[rules_] := ReplaceAll[Global`var, rules]
```

in your function.  Then

```
replace[var -> 0]
replace[Test`Private`var -> 0]
```

yields

```
0
var
```

as I think you'd like.

Comment: What is the outcome of making this change?

Comment: It won't work if the user works in a notebook that has a CellContext->Notebook.

Comment: @Kuba Huh, never heard of that option.  Is it in widespread use?  I'm interested because I'm working on a package that uses that Global` context a bit.

Comment: @ChrisK I'm not using it but you never know what are preferences of the end user :)

Comment: What may be more problematic though, is when someone want's to use `replace` inside a package. Then the context will be definitely different.

Comment: @ChrisK  I use `Evaluation>NoteBook's Default Context>Unique to This Notebook` routinely to avoid cross-talk among open notebooks (including Mathematica documentation).

Comment: @ChrisK I have the context unique to each notebook set as the default. I think of each notebook as its own programme. I don't create anything in the Global context.

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of [Formal Symbols](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/LettersAndLetterLikeForms.html).

```
BeginPackage["Test`"];
replace::usage = "Returns \[FormalV]/.rules.";

Begin["`Private`"];

 replace[rules_] := \[FormalV] /.rules

End[];
EndPackage[];
```

Then in the notebook.

```
replace[\[FormalV] -> 0]
(* 0 *)
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does this work for any symbol already on the `$ContextPath` during both package initialization and in the notebook, but not defined?

Answer (score 3):

> is there some way to take the call `ReplaceAll[var, rules]`and make it forget contexts for a minute?

```
BeginPackage["Test`"];
replace::usage = "Returns var/.rules.";
print;
Begin["`Private`"];
replace[rules_] := ReplaceAll[Symbol[$Context <> "var"], rules]

End[];
EndPackage[];
```

Not general, but works.