# How to put replacement rules into a package

Tags: replacement, packages

I have a replacement rules list, but its quite long and therefore I would like to make a standalone package of it. I tried but haven't succeeded. A simple example of my approach is

```
BeginPackage["Rules`"]

Rules::usage="Rules[x] applies rules on expression x."

Begin["Private`"]

RulesDef = {a->2,b->3};
Rules[expr_]:=expr//.RulesDef

End[]
EndPackage[]
```

However, when I call `Rules[a + b]`, it gives me `a + b` instead of `5`.

How should I put such a rules into a package, if it is possible?

Comment: closely related: [104584](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/104584/5478)

Comment: I saw this, however, if I understand it right, I have reverse problem, I wan to pass rules from the package, not into.

Comment: Yes, but it's closely related so I've linked it for future visitors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you want your rules to be evaluated in the same context as the expression you are applying them to, I don't think a real package is what you want. I think saving your rule definition in a package (`.m`) file without the package trimmings -- which create a new context -- will work for you.

1. Make a new notebook with just one cell containing

   ```
   myRules = {a -> 2, b -> 3};
   ```
2. Make the cell a initialization cell.
3. Save the notebook to `FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications"}]` as `myRules.m`.

Now in any note book you can write

```
<< "myRules.m"
a + b /. myRules
```

> `5`

As an alternative, if you have V10.2 or later, you could make `myRules` a [`LocalSymbol`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LocalSymbol.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately, it is not working for me. I says: "{myRules} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid \
dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing." Moreover, the set of commands I would like to put into the package also contains some functions which should manipulate the expression in the notebook according to their definition in the package and the replacement rules (idealy also in the same package :) ).

Comment: And also I have Mathematica 10.0.

Comment: @fales. You must have done something wrong. To get an idea of what is going wrong, evaluate `myRules` immediately after loading `myRules.m` with `<<` -- you should see `{a -> 2, b -> 3}`. As to your second issue, you could put `myRules = {a -> 2, b -> 3};` in an **initialization cell** at beginning of your package file (before `BeginPackage[]`).

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: Thank you for reaction, you are of course right, it was my fault. I don't know how, anyway, all lines got commented during the save to .m

Comment: @fales. All cells except those that have been given the **initialization cell** property become comments when a file is saves as a .m file. That's why I emphasized "initialization cell" in my previous comment.

Answer (score 3):

I think using the usual package syntax is fine. You just need to add the Symbol RulesDef to the global context. Thus your package could look like this:

```
BeginPackage["Rules`"]

RulesDef::usage="Boo"
Rules::usage="Rules[x] applies rules on expression x."

Begin["Private`"]

RulesDef = {Global`a->2,Global`b->3};
Rules[expr_]:=expr//.RulesDef

End[]
EndPackage[]
```

Its necessary to addd Global` infront of the variables cause otherwise their context will be private.