# Why is pattern matching different inside package

Tags: pattern-matching, packages

This works fine when put in a notebook:

```
TestFunction2[x_] := Column[{Head /@ x, Cases[x, _f], MatchQ[_f] /@ x}];
TestFunction2[{f[1, 2]}]
```

and produces:

```
{f}
{f{1,2}}
{True}
```

However if the function is put in a package, for example:

```
BeginPackage["Test`"]
TestFunction::usage=""
Begin["`Private`"]
TestFunction[x_]:=Column[{Head/@x,Cases[x,_f],MatchQ[_f]/@x}];
End[]
EndPackage[]
```

and then used from a notebook:

```
Needs["Test`"];
TestFunction[{f[1, 2]}]
```

it produces:

```
{f}
{}
{False}
```

Why?

---

Edit:

My example was not detailed enough to explain what I want to achieve. I indeed want to have `f` that is defined in the context of `` Test` ``. This is because I want to use it as a type inside the package `Test`.

This is for example because I want to distinguish between two different arrays and wrap one of them for example in `f[{1,2,3}]` and another one in `g[{1,2,3,}]` and thus make distinction how they should be processed in `Test`.

Comment: Without trying your code: `f` is created as ``Test`Private`f`` in `TestFunction`, but you are matching against ``Global`f``

Comment: At least closely related: [104584](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/104584/5478), [112151](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/112151/5478), [114769](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114769/5478)

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that f is created as  `` Test`Private`f ``. Modifying the code in the package like this:

```
BeginPackage["Test`"]
TestFunction::usage=""
f::usage=""
Begin["`Private`"]
TestFunction[x_]:=Column[{Head/@x,Cases[x,_f],MatchQ[_f]/@x}];
End[]
EndPackage[]
```

will make it work.

Thank you Szabolcs for pointing this out!

Thanks to Kuba for pointing out the linked examples!

Comment: Of course, the naming must be done carefully. I prefer not to change the question as the reader then can follow the discussion as it was.

Comment: It is not a discussion panel. SE format is Clear question <-> valid answers. Your answer didn not fit your question. I moved your clarification.